# Проверка на безопасность

Tags: php, безопасность

Есть ли уязвимости в данном коде?

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) {

    $language = $_COOKIE['lang'];

    $result = "en";

    if (in_array($language, $LANGS)) {

        $result = $language;
    }

    @setcookie("lang", $result, time() + 14 * 24 * 3600, "/");
    include_once("../sys/lang/".$result.".php");

}  else {

    $language = "en";

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) {

        $language = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
    }

    $result = "en";

    if (in_array($language, $LANGS)) {

        $result = $language;
    }

    @setcookie("lang", $result, time() + 14 * 24 * 3600, "/");
    include_once("../sys/lang/".$result.".php");
}
```

Comment: Вас интересует только безопасность? Вас не смущает, что в коде совершенно зря дублируются одни и те же действия?

Answer (score 2):

Проверяйте куку не на существование, а на пустоту. Плюс размер вашего кода можно уменьшить.

Готовый вариант:

```
$result = 'en';

if(!empty($_COOKIE['lang']) && in_array($_COOKIE['lang'], $LANGS)) {
    $result = $_COOKIE['lang'];
}else if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) {
    $language = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
    if (in_array($language, $LANGS)) $result = $language;
}

setcookie('lang', $result, time() + 14 * 24 * 3600, '/');
include_once('../sys/lang/'.$result.'.php');
```

Comment: undefined index.

Comment: @Total Pusher благодарю за пример, правда не понятно, как он относится к обсуждаемому выше коду? В скрипте стоит проверка на существование переменной и обратиться к ней можно только, если она установлена

Comment: Да, вы правы. Почему-то думал, что empty при обращении к несуществующему хешу выдает ворнинг. Не выдает.

Answer (score -1):

Не понятно что вы хотели бы услышать, но конечно же не безопасно, простой кайс взлома.

1. Пишем скрипт test.php
2. Аплодим на сайт через форму
3. Находим coockie lang='../../../uploads/test.php'
4. Success!

Содержимое test.php

```
<?php
  echo 'test';
```

Comment: щито? 1) Где вы тут форму нашли? 2) Как вы что-то искать собрались? 3) Если вы сможете через форму загрузить пхп скрипт, тут дело не в этом куске а в форме.

Comment: @Manitikyl Шыре мыслите вы даёте возможность исполнить любой скрипт на сервере через include, а это уже дыра.

Comment: @Naumov почему любой? Там ведь стоит проверка in_array. Т.е. могут инклудится только те скрипты, которые разработчиком прописаны в массиве $LANGS

Comment: @skarb через полгода уберут проверку и все, что бы автоматом includit'ь

Comment: @Naumov ха)) Признали бы уже ошибку свою, вместо введения в замешательство. Следуя вашей логике, для надежной безопасности сайт вообще следует перенести на свой домашний компьютер и отключиться от интернета

Comment: @skarb для безопасности сайта надо как минимум думать и о будущем

Answer (score -1):

Для PHP7+ можно использовать [оператор объединения с null](http://php.net/manual/ru/migration70.new-features.php) `??`.

Будет так:

```
$result = $_COOKIE['lang'] ?? (
    isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) ? substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2) : 'en'
);
if (!in_array($result, $LANGS)) $result = 'en';
setcookie('lang', $result, time() + 14 * 24 * 3600, '/');
include_once('../sys/lang/'.$result.'.php');
```

Comment: Кодинг стаил нервно курит, и разрабы php7+ колят глаза

Comment: @Naumov что конкретно вам не нравится в этом примере, чтобы понять свою ошибку? Сложная конструкция разбита на 2 через вынос на отдельную строку.